# How to boot from my LIVE USB?

Tags: boot, windows-8, live-usb

I cannot get the screen by repeatedly pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> or any other screen.

Comment: The keys needed depend on the make and model of your machine. Can you update you question with information about your hardware and how you created the live usb.

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu! It depends on your laptop model. What laptop do you have?

Comment: The following link will help you http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

For Different Systems you'll need to press different keys.
.
Till now, I've some working keys that have helped me to boot till now.
.

- ESC
- F2
- F12
- DEL
- F9

Note : F8 is for Diagnostic Tools, Safe Mode,etc in Windows..

Answer (score 0):

from windows 8 press the restart button (on the charms menu) while holding shift. If the usb is recognized there should be an option to boot from device, elsewise go to advanced settings and select uefi settings (or something like that) and you should be presented with your mobo's settings